# Tips & Tricks - Working with Axure & Fireworks Combined

Tags: wireframe, axure

I've used Adobe Fireworks for a number of years for wireframing and hi-fi prototypes. However, I have recently switched over to Axure, as the team i'm working in uses it quite heavily.

I was wondering if anybody can recommend any tricks or tips for using the two programs side by side?

Comment: There is no answer to this question, it's more of a discussion topic. If there is one specific query about whether it is more appropriate to use Axure of Fireworks to do 'X' then that's something we can answer, but this isn't really the site to ask for tips and tricks.

Comment: Ok, point taken @JonW... Will be conscious of that in future. Was looking for peoples real life experiences in using the two programs together, not really 'tips and tricks'. I guess I should have worded my question differently.

Comment: Asking for people's experiences in using something is still too discussion-y for this site I'm afraid. It needs to be a specific question that you have, usually based on a problem you're trying to overcome. Discussions are just not really what StackExchange format is set up to handle effectively.

Answer (score 3):

In my team, some members use Fireworks and others use Axure.

**A tip:** 
the tools used to create prototypes are of lesser importance, as long as the end results communicate the ideas efficiently towards the stakeholders. Leave the choice up to the designers to decide which tool they want to use. They will produce results faster, more time for evaluation and rework -> results in a better experience.

**Keep in mind:** 
if a lot of handovers occur inside the team, might be best to go for one tool. This way everybody knows this tool and work is easier interchangeable.

Working in smaller organisations it is often cheaper to head into one direction (licencing costs).

Answer (score 1):

For what purpose are you using them side-by-side? They are really two separate tools. FW is great for hi fidelity visual mockups. Axure is OK for low fidelity clickable wireframes.

I guess my tip would be to keep them segregated. Using Axure for hi-fi prototyping can be a huge pain and is something I strongly suggest you avoid.